# How to fix InvalidArgument= Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index in exporting listview items to excel

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm setting up a program, and want to save my listview items to Excel, but there's always an error in saving my items.

I;m using Windows 7 and Visual Basic 2010. There are actually 3 columns, and an unexpected number of rows since I'm running a food menu program, so the number of subitems are unexpected.

```vb
Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
        Dim ExcelSheet As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
        ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

        With ExcelSheet
            For i = 1 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count
                .cells(i, 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i - 1).Text
                For j = 1 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
                    .cells(i, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i - 1).SubItems(j).Text
                Next
            Next
        End With
        ExcelApp.Visible = True
        ExcelSheet = Nothing
        ExcelBook = Nothing
        ExcelApp = Nothing
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I expect it to display on the Excel program with the following listview items, but there's just an error, so it can't proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below updated code:

```
Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
        Dim ExcelSheet As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
        ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

        With ExcelSheet
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
           .cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i).Text
        Next
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
           For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
              .cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
           Next
        Next
        End With
        ExcelApp.Visible = True
        ExcelSheet = Nothing
        ExcelBook = Nothing
        ExcelApp = Nothing
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! But there are extra columns, and I tried to edit the columns and delete them, but it's still there

Comment: Order List Price List Quantity Order List Price List
Burger Meal 3 299 1  
Burger Meal 2 219 1  
Regular Burger 59 1  
Nachos 99 1  

There are two extra columns in the Excel worksheet
I've tried to delete all columns, and readjust the indices, but still it didn't work.
Appreciate all your help.